How can I customize Django Rest Framework documentation without using decorators?
I'm currently working on a Django project and utilizing Django Rest Framework (DRF) for building APIs. I've integrated drf-pectacular for automatic API documentation generation, but I'm finding that using decorators to customize the documentation is making my codebase messy.
I'm interested in exploring alternative approaches to customize my DRF documentation without relying heavily on decorators. Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this? I'm specifically looking for methods or techniques that allow me to customize the documentation while keeping my code clean and maintainable.
Any suggestions, examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Look at the source code for the decorators and do the same thing in another way?

There are several auto generating docs libraries for DRF, The main thing is you
want to customize your docs.

The drf-yasg is using OpenAPI 2 as the docs says https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html

But drf-pectacular is using OpenAPI 3 as the docs says
https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html
in drf-yasg docs state that if you want to use OpenAPI 3 use drf-pectacular https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#openapi-3-0-note
But in general, if you want to customize your docs, most of these kind of libraries use decorators to customize the output of your documents.
Here you can read how to customize your docs with drf-yasg: https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html
My recommendation is to stick with what you have, and try to clean up your docs based on your serializers, and use docstrings for a description of your API endpoint.

You can use "drf_yasg" module here. You just need to pass a docstring for your serializers and views like this :
class MyModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    """
       doc string goes here
    """
    model = MyModel
    fields = []

views.py
class MyAPIViewClass(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
       doc string goes here
    """
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

so "drf_yasg" will create your documentation.
